# Why there is a difference in size reported by lsblk, gdisk and parted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, parted

```
[anaconda root@861767 ~]# lsblk /dev/sda
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1         8:1    0   512M  0 part 
└─sda2         8:2    0 465.3G  0 part 
  ├─sys-root 253:2    0    10G  0 lvm  
  ├─sys-var  253:3    0     4G  0 lvm  
  ├─sys-tmp  253:4    0     4G  0 lvm  
  └─sys-home 253:5    0 447.3G  0 lvm  
[anaconda root@861767 ~]# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.6

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2029 sectors (1014.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   0700  
   2         1050624       976773119   465.3 GiB   8E00  
[anaconda root@861767 ~]# parted -s /dev/sda unit GB print
Model: ATA GB0500EAFYL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      0.00GB  0.54GB  0.54GB  ext4
 2      0.54GB  500GB   500GB                      lvm

[anaconda root@861767 ~]#
```

lsblk and gdisk reports the disk size is 465.5G
parted says the size is 500G

Which one is real? And why there is inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk manufacturers advertise disk sizes in multiples of 1000. That is, a "KB" is 1000 and *not* 1024 as software people are used to.

For you, it seems that `lsblk` and `gdisk` are using the 1024 value but `parted` is using 1000.

```
465.5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 == 499,826,819,072
```

Now, divide:

```
499,826,819,072 / (1000 * 1000 * 1000) == 499.826
```

which maps to the `500` that `parted` is reporting

Notice that `lsblk` and `gdisk` use `GiB` but you gave the `GB` option to `parted`.  Try `parted` with the `GiB` option